# Are you supposed to give the engine gas when shifting gears?

Tags: clutch, manual-transmission

I'm learning how to drive manual. When I switch gears, I just stop giving it gas, push in the clutch, select the gear, and let out the clutch. After the clutch is out, I give it gas. This works smoothly every time. But, I've been reading online, and it says that I have to give it gas while I'm letting out the clutch, after selecting the gear. What is the right way to do it? Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you ask this question in [The Pitstop](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/340/the-pitstop) chat room.

Answer (score 1):

If it works smoothly, then it should be fine, although I'm surprised it works smoothly.

Generally, vehicles like some fuel/petrol to be introduced as the clutch is being released.  Basically, the more I release the clutch, the more fuel I give.  When the clutch is completely released, I'm giving the appropriate amount of fuel for the speed I want to maintain.

How you are doing it should actually achieve slightly better MPG, because gas delivered while the clutch is depressed is partially wasted (100% wasted if the clutch is fully depressed).